# Navigate to Erroractivity when exception occure in android application

Tags: android, error-handling, exception, nullpointerexception

I have developed some of native android application. I want to show error activity if any exception from code.Its same like in Asp.Net Custom Error Page.Is there any way to navigate to specific error activity when error is occurred?

Comment: Are you doing this inside try{}catch(){}? Why not navigate inside Catch?

Comment: actually there is so many exception which can occur in android native application like invalidargumentexception or nullpointer exception but i want to navigate to my custom activity when exception occurred.. and i want to show message to end user that "Something went wrong".So is there any way from which i can do this?

Comment: You can have the possible exceptions types then depending on the type of exception expected , start the activity with some intent extras as the message to show